# How to change the font smoothing (anti-aliasing) quality of a RichEdit in Delphi?

Tags: delphi, delphi-7, antialiasing, richedit, trichedit

I have a **Delphi 7** application where I'm drawing text to a `TBitmap`. I need to be able to control the anti-aliasing quality of the text. For this purpose I'm using the following procedure:

```
procedure SetFontQuality(Font: TFont; Quality: Byte);
var
  lf: TLogFont;
begin
  GetObject(Font.Handle, SizeOf(TLogFont), @lf);
  lf.lfQuality := Quality;
  Font.Handle := CreateFontIndirect(lf);
end;
```

I'm calling it for my `TBitmap` like this: `SetFontQuality(MyBitmap.Canvas.Font, ANTIALIASED_QUALITY)`. The goal here is to set the old anti-aliasing instead of the new ClearType one.
This works great, if I'm using `DrawText` to draw the text on the `TBitmap`.
However, I need to draw the text of a `TRichEdit` on it, so I'm using `EM_FORMATRANGE` for this purpose. But the text is drawn with whatever my Windows anti-aliasing is (so if I enable ClearType in Windows, it is ClearType, even if I set the old anti-aliasing with `ANTIALIASED_QUALITY`).

I suppose I need to change the font quality of the `TRichEdit`, so I applied the procedure to it: `SetFontQuality(MyRichEdit.Font, ANTIALIASED_QUALITY)`, but that didn't change things.

I did a little bit of testing - I tried applying the procedure to the `Font` property of various controls - `TButton`, `TMemo`, `TEdit`, `TLabel`. It works like a charm on all of them. But when applied to a `TRichEdit`'s `Font` property, the anti-aliasing doesn't change.

So, my question is: **how do I change the anti-aliasing quality of a TRichEdit control?**

Comment: @FreeConsulting `SelAttributes` neither is a `TFont` property, nor it contains one.

Comment: `SelAttributes` is a `TTextAttributes` property that specifies font properties. None of which is the quality.

Comment: Exactly. It seems MS didn't really think that issue through (not the SelAttributes thing, but the control's anti-aliasing quality issue).

Answer (score 2):

A Delphi `TRichEdit` control is a loose wrapper around the native Windows rich edit control. The Windows rich edit control is based on the RTF standard. The content of the rich edit control can have different font properties for different parts of the text. The RTF standard, however, does not cover anti-aliasing. Thus you cannot apply an anti-aliasing setting to individual parts of the text. The control therefore uses the system setting to determine anti-aliasing.

Comment: So, you're saying it's not possible? I don't expect to be able to set different anti-aliasing to different parts of the text, but surely they (Microsoft) could (and should) have easily implemented a way to set the global anti-aliasing of the entire control (and that's what I want to do). It's obviously not fixed, as it respects the system settings, so why not just let the programmers be able to set it themselves? If they really didn't implement a way, that's a big miss on their part.

Comment: @jedi - Find all about rich edit [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb787605%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: @Sertac if I had found something on this issue on msdn, I would not have asked the question. If you have found something about anti-aliasing there, then please, do share the exact link.

Comment: @jedi - No, I posted the link as an evidence that rich edit does not have any explicit support for font quality. It should be obvious that it would need explicit support since it have the capability to render different fonts and hence a `WM_SETFONT` is not deterministic like other controls.

Comment: @Sertac Yeah, seems like I'm stuck.